# Jasmine TimeOut error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I am writing a karma unit test script. Everything looks fine but i am getting error:

```
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Windows 7) Unit: common.services.PartialUpdater Should be loaded with all dependencies FAILED
        Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Windows 7): Executed 4 of 4 (1 FAILED) (5.025 secs / 5.006 secs)
```

Function where it drop:

```
describe("Unit: common.services.PartialUpdater", function() {


      it("Should be loaded with all dependencies", function($rootScope) {                
          expect(true).toBe(true);
          jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 20000;
      });

      it("Should make a partial update when event is received", function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 20000;
      });

});
```

I don't want to increase jasme.default timeout interval more and don't know how else i could fix this.  Is here anybody who have some experianec with this kind of problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Jasmine are you running?

In 2.0 the first parameter in a test is the asynchronous callback function and it has to be called for the test to register complete.

Try changing your test to this.

```
  it("Should be loaded with all dependencies", function(done) {                
      expect(true).toBe(true);
      // you probably don't need this any more.
      //jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 20000;
      done();
  });
```

Or just remove the done parameter from the function and make it synchronous.